# App crashed on UITableview didSelectRow "index 0 beyond bounds for empty NSArray"

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, crash

I have a datasource array to populate the tableView. And the datasource is modified from a method "reloadContent". At the end of reloadContent, Im doing [tableview reloadData].
App crashed on didSelectRow when accessing [datasource objectAtIndex:indexPath.row].
Can it be possible that datasource got modified and we clicked on tableView before it reflected on UI. If that is the case, what should be the solution.
This issue happened very very rarely while testing.

```
 - (void) reloadContent {
    self.datasource = [self getCurrentItems]; //Modified the datasource here
    <Do some Calculations and set tableView frame and other stuff> 
    [self.tableView reloadData];
 }
```

After datasource is modified there is not much wait time, like network call or anything. There is some functions like setting tableView header, some calculations, frame setting etc. If these calculations and reloadData is taking time, how to handle the situation.

Comment: if the content reload takes time, you need to prevent the user from interacting with the screen until its done. This is true of any async method, fetching data from a network, database, processing images, encrypting/decrypting something etc

Comment: Please present your code ... Your modification on datatsource etc.

Comment: Question is modified with the sample code. @SimonMcLoughlin , there is no data fetching from network/database. There are some things like setting tableview header, tableview frame setting etc.

Comment: There shouldn't be issue if when setting `self.datasource` and `reloadData` are "close" and in same thread. If you set the `datasource` in background and reload in main (since it's UI related), a small unsync might occur. But `didSelect` should happen in main thread since it's User interaction, so your datasource should be correct at this point. It's a strange case you have...

Comment: @Larme yes it is rare scenario. Normally datasource on reloadContent and didSelectRow will be same.